# Not found error in php social network all the time

Tags: php, controller, http-status-code-404, social-networking

I was reading through the book PHP 5 Social Networking by Michael Peacock. It is about creating a framework for social network. It uploaded the source code to the server, created the database and it worked all fine untill after i reuploaded the source code again and now all the time I get error message "Error 404 not found". As I understand the whole thing works through one main controller - "index.php" and then pases the controll to other controllers, based on what it is supposed to do. Here is the index.php code:

```
<?php

session_start();

DEFINE("FRAMEWORK_PATH", dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" );


require('registry/registry.class.php');
$registry = new Registry();
// setup our core registry objects
$registry->createAndStoreObject( 'template', 'template' );
$registry->createAndStoreObject( 'mysqldb', 'db' );
$registry->createAndStoreObject( 'authenticate', 'authenticate' );
$registry->createAndStoreObject( 'urlprocessor', 'url' );
$registry->getObject('url')->getURLData();
// database settings
include(FRAMEWORK_PATH . 'config.php');
// create a database connection
$registry->getObject('db')->newConnection( $configs['db_host_sn'], $configs['db_user_sn'], $configs['db_pass_sn'], $configs['db_name_sn']);

$registry->getObject('authenticate')->checkForAuthentication();

// store settings in our registry
$settingsSQL = "SELECT `key`, `value` FROM settings";
$registry->getObject('db')->executeQuery( $settingsSQL );
while( $setting = $registry->getObject('db')->getRows() )
{
    $registry->storeSetting( $setting['value'], $setting['key'] );
}
$registry->getObject('template')->getPage()->addTag( 'siteurl', $registry->getSetting('siteurl') );
$registry->getObject('template')->buildFromTemplates('header.tpl.php', 'main.tpl.php', 'footer.tpl.php');

$controllers = array();
$controllersSQL = "SELECT * FROM controllers WHERE active=1";
$registry->getObject('db')->executeQuery( $controllersSQL );
while( $controller = $registry->getObject('db')->getRows() )
{
    $controllers[] = $controller['controller'];
}
$controller = $registry->getObject('url')->getURLBit(0);


if( $registry->getObject('authenticate')->isLoggedIn() )
{
    $registry->getObject('template')->addTemplateBit('userbar', 'userbar_loggedin.tpl.php');
    $registry->getObject('template')->getPage()->addTag( 'username', $registry->getObject('authenticate')->getUser()->getUsername() );

}
else
{
    $registry->getObject('template')->addTemplateBit('userbar', 'userbar.tpl.php');
}


if( in_array( $controller, $controllers ) )
{

    require_once( FRAMEWORK_PATH . 'controllers/' . $controller . '/controller.php');
    $controllerInc = $controller.'controller';
    $controller = new $controllerInc( $registry, true );

}
else
{
    // default controller, or pass control to CMS type system?
}


$registry->getObject('template')->parseOutput();
print $registry->getObject('template')->getPage()->getContentToPrint();


?>
```

I really cant understand what is up!

Comment: I am not quite sure yet where lies the problem. I think it is somewhere in index.php but I can paste other code, I am just not sure where to look for the problem.

Comment: did .htaccess make it up on the second UL? Also, might be a permissions problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was something about .htaccess. I am just learning, and this book is the first big thing I am studying. Can you tell about .htaccess more, becasue I am not sure what was supposed to happen with it.

Comment: Oh yep I am strating figuring it out. It is an apache web server config file, and to let this contoroller system work. It is mentioned in the book.